# Adding names to numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, printing

I have a 2D numpy array:

```
my_array = numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
```

When I print it, it comes out like this:

```
>>> print(my_array)
[[1 2]
 [3 4]]
```

Is it possible to put labels or names on the output? For instance let's say I have

```
names = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
```

then I want

```
a [[1 2]
b  [3 4]]
    c d
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, but… it sounds like you might be interested in [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't you want [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)?

```
>>> import numpy
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> my_array = numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> pd.DataFrame(my_array, columns=list('cd'), index=list('ab'))
   c  d
a  1  2
b  3  4
```

Comment: I don't think this is really an answer; he's asking how to do this with NumPy. (That's why I wrote the same thing as a comment.)

Comment: @abarnert Ok, let's wait for OP to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* do this with [`np.savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html#numpy.savetxt), but it's going to be really hacky.

Alternatively, you can just post-process the `str` or `repr`, but that's *really* ugly—it will get worse with more complex arrays, but even for a fixed 2x2 array, it's something like:

```
def format_my_2x2_array(a):
    s = str(a).splitlines()
    s[0] = 'a ' + s[0]
    s[1] = 'b ' + s[1]
    col0 = s[1].find('[') + 1
    col1 = s[1].find(' ', col0) + 1
    s.append(' ' * col0 + 'c' + ' ' * (col1 - col0 - 1) + 'd')
    return '\n'.join(s)
```

To do it in a clean way, you will need to iterate over the contents manually and join them up yourself, just as you would for a normal Python list of lists that you wanted to print out NumPy-style.

If the column and row names are an inherent part of your data, you probably don't want to tack them off after the fact in I/O functions, but rather store them with the data. That's exactly what [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) is good for—basically, a DataFrame can be used as an array with names for the indices. That doesn't help if you want to do this with NumPy, but in the same way you want to use NumPy instead of lists of lists to, e.g., operate on matrices or large pixel arrays, you want to use Pandas instead of NumPy to, e.g., operate on structures with named rows and columns.